# pip install not treating dependencies correctly, when that dependency is numpy/scipy/... (a few others)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, virtualenv

I'm building a virtualenv (system details follow) and numpy, scipy and pandas don't seem to be treated correctly as a dependency.

To clarify, this problem seems to exist regardless of whether numpy appears in the requirements.txt, even if they are placed in the correct order.

This is inconvenient, and the opposite of how a package manager is supposed to work, I think :)

So what gives? When I build the virtualenv from scratch, this is the output:

```
[bdundee@etl-dev Py26]$ ls
requirements.txt  requirements.txt~
[bdundee@etl-dev Py26]$ virtualenv ./env/sqrt_python26 --no-site-packages
New python executable in ./env/sqrt_python26/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
[bdundee@etl-devPy26]$ source ./env/sqrt_python26/bin/activate
(sqrt_python26)[bdundee@etl-devPy26]$ pip install -r ./requirements.txt 
Downloading/unpacking Bottleneck==0.8.0 (from -r ./requirements.txt (line 6))

...

    import numpy as np

ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Clearly numpy should be treated as a dependency of Bottleneck and isn't. The same problem occurs with matplotlib.

Bottleneck is not the only module with this issue, there are a few others. This has forced me to create pre_pip.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

## Install numpy                                                                                                                                                                      
pip install numpy==1.7.1

## Install scipy                                                                                                                                                                      
pip install scipy==0.12.0

## Install pandas                                                                                                                                                                     
pip install pandas==0.12.0
```

I'm also running in to errors with scipy and pandas (for example, statsmodels).

The question(s):

- Are these bugs in the setup instructions for these packages?
- Is this a numpy-specific thing?
- Is there a way to solve this without a "pre" build script that installs numpy, scipy and pandas?

System details:

- AWS CentOS (whatever the current version is)
- Python 2.6.9
- numpy 1.7.1

Comment: why not just add numpy etc.. to the requirements.txt

Comment: I have, but I get the same errors.

Comment: Does pip not install them in dependent order?

Comment: I thought that it should, but it doesn't seem to unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry I meant if you list them in order of dependency  does not install them in order?

Comment: I'm watching the install logs now. It _looks_ like what happens is that everything is downloaded, then `setup.py setup` is run, then `setup.py install` is run. If the setup step depends on numpy, scipy, etc., then it seems that the installation will fail. (The steps DO appear to be in order, though.) Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: I was not 100 percent on whether it was run once or per package  but it seems that it is all or nothing, setup.py is run at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pip seems to work as follows (feel free to correct me).

- Each file is downloaded and unpacked.
- Each file is built `python setup.py build`
- Each file is installed `python setup.py install`

The problem is that the `setup.py` files in some modules require the modules in question to be present during the build or install step, which is not possible if numpy/scipy/etc. are in the `requirements.txt`.

A [similar issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/720) exists for matplotlib, the pip community's sentiment is "it's not pip". Fair enough.

The best workaround, in my opinion, is to just write a wrapper. If anyone else knows any better ways, please let me know :)

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

INSTALL_DIR=$IMPORT/../Environment/Py26/env/sqrt_python26

## Step 1: build the virtualenv
virtualenv $INSTALL_DIR

## Now use the virtualenv
source $INSTALL_DIR/bin/activate

## Install numpy
pip install numpy==1.7.1

## Install scipy
pip install scipy==0.12.0

## Install pandas
pip install pandas==0.12.0

## Some others...
pip install patsy==0.2.1
pip install pycurl==7.19.0

## Now run requirements.txt
pip install -r ./requirements.txt

## finished, shut down virtualenv
deactivate
```

Comment: Several packages like statsmodels don't define numpy as a dependency, because pip **by default** upgrades dependencies whether you want or not. And I think it is **very** impolite to change the version of numpy or scipy that are installed in a users' python. There are a large number of packages that rely on numpy, and I never want anything to change the version without asking. It's one of my pet "hates" also because pip knows how to uninstall my numpy, but doesn't know how to install it from a binary (on Windows).

Comment: To be clear, I'm not arguing the design choice here--once you think it through it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an issue with a few different packages  using requirements.txt. You could use a script to  parse each line and run install, I am sure there are more elegant ways to do it but at least it will install in order so you won't get the errors,

```
import pip
with open("requirements.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        pip.main(['install', line])
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip--I've never seen `import pip` before :) I'm going to accept my answer, because I think it's a bit nicer.

Comment: No worries, it was a quick fix. You could chmod +x and symlink it to /usr/local/bin so it could be run from any directory. I think not specifying the package makes it more usable.